# How to align the card in flex that too in center?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have used card from bootstrap and since I want both the cards in same line I used flex but now both the cards are in same line but is aligned to top left. I want in in the center?

Could someone tell how to keep the flex in the center without using css if possible? And also provide some space between cards is also possible?

```
   import React from 'react';
    
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    
    import ButtonGroup from '@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup';
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { Nav, NavDropdown, NavItem } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        '& > *': {
          margin: theme.spacing(1),
        },
      },
    }));
    
    function SignUp() {
      
      return (
        <div>
          <br/>
          <br/>
        <div style={{display : 'flex'}} >
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <div class="card"  style={{width: '18rem'}}>
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" role="img"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
    
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Quick sample text to create the card title and make up the body of the card's content.</p>
        <Button>
                <Link class="nav-link" to="/manageexam/:id">
                  Manage Exam
                </Link>
                </Button>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      
    </div>
    <div class="card" style={{width: '18rem'}}>
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" role="img"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
    
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Quick sample text to create the card title and make up the body of the card's content.</p>
        <Button>
                <Link class="nav-link" to="/manageuser/:id">
                  Manage User
                </Link>
                </Button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
      
        
          
                {/*<Button><a href="http://localhost:3000/">LOGOUT</a></Button>*/}
                
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Please provide your current css - would be easier to help you. Also feel free to set up a fiddle :)

Comment: I Don't have any css as of now

Comment: Where does this classes come from? e.g. bd-placeholder-img card-img-top

Answer (score 0):

You can use justify-content: "center"(in code **justifyContent: "center"**) instead of alignItems: "center". And use the class in the div where you have written {display: flex}

Few points you need to correct:

1. You have written useStyles but have never used it.
2. Also, in React you have to use className instead of class.

Please check [Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-clarke-zzwix?file=/src/Signup.js)

Answer (score 0):

you can add `justifyContent:center` or `justifyContent:space-around` in your css